# Show TabPage header image on the right

Tags: c#, winforms, image, tabcontrol, tabpage

When you set ImageIndex (or ImageKey) for TabPage control image in tab's header is shown on the left.

[image]

How can i move it to the right?

Comment: The image your added is what you desire?

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed and implement the DrawItem event.  There's a good example in the MSDN Library article for it.

Pre-empting the next question: you'll need to implement the MouseUp event for the tab control and iterate the tabs, calling GetTabRect().  That lets you find out what tab was clicked and then find out if the mouse click was on the bitmap.

Comment: > "... There's a good example in the MSDN Library article for it."
You're so good at details. Where exactly on MSDN?

Comment: Go to search.microsoft.com, type in "tabcontrol.drawitem" and take the first hit.

Comment: Those examples are not good. Resulting tab headers look awful. They just to show that, yes, you can draw tab's header yourself. Pretty bad though.

Answer (score 0):

may be if you want something like [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29206-Custom-drawn-Close-button-TabControl.aspx), create close button on tabPage...